# Switching a button's appearence according to whether it's enabled or not

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm developing a wizard UI in which the user can go ahead only if the form matches some criteria.

So far, I have successfully developed all the logic behind the buttons, and the layout of the buttons themselves, so I can enable the forward button only when the user inserted some information.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnForward"
    style="@style/buttonForward_disabled"
    android:enabled="false" />
```

As you can see I used style attributes to describe when a button (which is technically a button with background drawable and text)

My `styles.xml` file contains the following

```
<style name="buttonFB">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">0.4</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">true</item>
</style>


<style name="buttonFB_disabled" parent="buttonFB">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:enabled">false</item>
</style>

<style name="buttonForward_disabled" parent="buttonFB_disabled">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btnfw_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/Forward</item>
</style>

<style name="buttonBackward_disabled" parent="buttonFB_disabled">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btnfw_disabled</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/Backward</item>
</style>
```

and buttons display correctly when they are instantiated into the layout. The obvious problem is that `Button.setEnabled(true)` only makes the button clickable but doesn't change the layout at all. In the example above you see that in both cases the text is white: it's expected to change in the immediate future as soon as I review all the graphics.

I have read that I cannot programmatically change the style of buttons at runtime. What can I do to make the buttons look different according to their enabled state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [selectors](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html). They are meant to do exactly what you want. Basically they define different styles to be applied to your button in accordance of the select, focused and enabled state.

Comment: In the example you linked I see there is choice for colours too. My Eclipse doesn't show me the android:color attribute: is it related to minimum SDK being 7 in my project?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the answer out of the top of my head. I have always used API level >= 8.

Comment: Don't worry I'll dig into this